# Can't make static position to angular-material inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, angular-material

I made a custom position for my select with `md-container-class` and it's working well.

This is my first chosen option: http://prntscr.com/c0oao4

I have a new problem, when I am choosing next `md-option`, it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/c0od78

Please help with finding solution, I have lost a lot of days for this and can't find the right way  to do it.
Maybe its angular-material bug or feature?

Comment: Are you sure they are `md-select`? They don't look like it. However, here's a CodePen copied from the example that works okay if it helps - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rLkwov

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c0olyh
yes its md-select, thanks for reference i will try to improve

Comment: OK. I have added `md-container-class` to each `md-select` and added some CSS to show how to position the dropdown.

Comment: so i tried it but, have a problem, my md-select-menu-container genetating in the and of the dom, not relative to container like in your instance 
http://prntscr.com/c15ijm
and its changing position according to the window height and width, what should i do?((

Comment: It's difficult to say, but one thing I use to stop elements changing when the window height changes is to add `flex='none'` to the element. So try that with your second `md-input-container` or `md-select`.

Comment: still no, thank u, i will answer if ill find something